# where/when should env.sample (.env) be pulled in? Is this a bug?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I was sourcing .env through my shell, which, I suspect, is a non-standard behavior, because this struck me as a bug:

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=string
```

along with all the other variables are not quoted with single-apostrophe ticks `'` ... which means that if there are characters that can be shell-evaluated, they will be.  This also affects urls because of the `&` that may be possible in their strings, as well as other shell characters.

Shouldn't it be

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='string'
```

?

Or am I doing it wrong .env never gets sourced by a shell?

Answer (score 1):

The .env file is read by the package django-environ and bears no relationship to either the python or shell formatting, it literally wants `<key>=<value>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the .env file is meant to be consumed by the `django-environ` package.

For detailed usage, check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ).